# MySQL Query from WP_PostMeta row to column

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i'm trying to make query from wordpress table wp_postmeta 
I need the data from `_form_id` to `_sub_id` on picture below.
I'm using this sql

```
SELECT meta_value,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_field_14' THEN meta_value END) as a1,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_field_15' THEN meta_value END) as a2,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_field_17' THEN meta_value END) as a3,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_field_18' THEN meta_value END) as a4
FROM wp_postmeta
Group by post_id
```

but the `NULL` data on a1 to a4 are still appear on the result. 
my [SQL Fiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f3b35/4)
please advise, thank you

[image]

expected result
[image: expected result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select `post_id`, meta_value is not present in `group by` so you will get a random value from each post

Also only posts 54,56, 57 have these fields, so rest of the posts will get NULL value.

```
SELECT post_id,
                MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_field_14' THEN meta_value  END) as a1,
                MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_field_15' THEN meta_value  END) as a2,
                MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_field_17' THEN meta_value  END) as a3,
                MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_field_18' THEN meta_value  END) as a4
                FROM wp_postmeta
                Group by post_id
```

EDIT:

as per the result, you just want meta values from all posts that have values, you can use subquery and coalesce to get what you want

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_field_14' THEN meta_value END) as a1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_field_15' THEN meta_value END) as a2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_field_17' THEN meta_value END) as a3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_field_18' THEN meta_value END) as a4
FROM wp_postmeta
Group by post_id
)T
where coalesce(a1,a2,a3,a4) is not null
```

Comment: thank you @radar but the NULL on a1 to a4 still appear, any idea?

Comment: @vincmeister, as these meta keys are not present for other posts you get NULLs, if you see posts 54,56,57 get proper values. if you want data for only specific post add where post_id = 54 before group by

Comment: i want general result without select post_id, in case i have 40 post_id, all of them will appear. the same parameter is meta_key = _form_id , with meta_value = 3 . Is it possible to query? thanks again

Comment: @vincmeister, can you post sample expected data?